# GroupBy Remove leading rows and last rows based on a column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe `df` :-

| ID | Date | Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 30-10-2013 | Success |
| 1 | 08-11-2013 | Success |
| 1 | 06-12-2013 | Success |
| 1 | 24-02-2014 | Click |
| 1 | 24-02-2014 | Form |
| 1 | 04-03-2014 | Email |
| 1 | 15-04-2014 | Success |
| 1 | 16-04-2014 | Click |
| 1 | 17-05-2014 | Success |
| 1 | 21-06-2014 | Email |
| 1 | 01-07-2014 | Webpage |
| 1 | 03-07-2014 | Email |
| 2 | 05-07-2014 | Form |
| 2 | 06-08-2014 | Webpage |
| 2 | 07-09-2014 | Success |

I want to remove rows which have `Event` `Success` if the `Event` starts with `Success` for each `ID` (sorted in chronological order) and also remove the events(rows) after the last `Success` Event for each `ID`.
Expected :-

| ID | Date | Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 24-02-2014 | Click |
| 1 | 24-02-2014 | Form |
| 1 | 04-03-2014 | Email |
| 1 | 15-04-2014 | Success |
| 1 | 16-04-2014 | Click |
| 1 | 17-05-2014 | Success |
| 2 | 05-07-2014 | Form |
| 2 | 06-08-2014 | Webpage |
| 2 | 07-09-2014 | Success |

Comment: The logic is unclear, you only want to remove the leading Success per group and rows after last success?

Comment: I have given the expected output.. If Id starts with `Success` I need to remove( for each User id sorted chronological order) and alsoevents after last `Success` event for each user to be removed

Comment: I'm asking because an example is not always representative of the generic case nor sufficient to describe a logic.

Comment: yes you are right. If each user is sorted chronologically, and if it starts with success event I want to remove that and if the user has any events post his/her last `success` event I want to remove that as well

Comment: @Scope Why there's `success` in row with `15-04-2014` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided the dataframe is already sorted, this should work:

```
df["n"] = df.groupby("ID")["Event"].transform(lambda x: (x == "Success").shift(1, fill_value=0).cumsum())
df["keep"] = df.groupby(["ID", "n"])["Event"].transform(lambda x: (len(x) > 1) & (x.iloc[-1] == "Success"))
result = df.loc[df["keep"]].drop(columns=["keep", "n"])
```

A bit of explanation:

- "n" numbers a group of rows containing one "Success", using this trick: https://www.codeforests.com/2021/03/30/group-consecutive-rows-in-pandas/
- "keep" creates a filter based on row group containing more than 1 row (not only a single "Success") and the last row being "Success"

Updated version (according to the comments):

```
df["n"] = df.groupby("ID")["Event"].transform(lambda x: (x == "Success").shift(1, fill_value=0).cumsum())
df["keep"] = df.groupby(["ID", "n"])["Event"].transform(lambda x: (len(x) > 1))
df = df.loc[df["keep"]]  # remove leading "Success" rows
df["keep"] = df.groupby("ID")["n"].transform(lambda x: x != x.max() if len(x.unique()) > 1 else True)
df = df.loc[df["keep"]]  # remove trailing rows after last "Success"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. What if I only have to remove only leading `Success` and keep the rest?

Comment: You can remove `(x.iloc[-1] == "Success")` to keep groups which do not end with "Success".

Comment: `transform(lambda x: (len(x) > 1)` this is basically to filter for Events which have consecutive `Success` when grouped by `ID` chronologically?

Comment: Yes, consecutive "Success" will go to different groups (different "n") with length of 1.

Comment: Right ..consecutive Successes only if it starts with event `success` for each group

Comment: this is removing all the consecutive `Success` present any where in the group and retainign just one whereas I want to remove only those present at the start of the group. Like if a group starts with one `Success` or n number of `Success` events consecutively I just want to remove that

Comment: For example if a group has `Success`, `Success`,`Click`,`Form`,`Email` in this case (when group starts with consecutive `Success` events only those should be removed and output shoulf still retain ,`Click`,`Form`,`Email`. Another case when a group starts with`Success`, `Success`,`Click`,`Form`,`Success`,`Success`,`Email`,`Form` , then output should have `Click`,`Form`,`Success`,`Success` .

Comment: I added another version based on your comments, but please update the question to take into account all the edge cases you would like to cover. In any case, the processing should be very similar to the ones posted.

Comment: I have updated here with a few examples :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73359021/group-by-remove-groupsrows-based-on-condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247278/discussion-between-scope-and-bzu).