# Group By : Remove groups(rows) based on condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe `df` :-

| ID | Date | Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 04-09-2013 | Success |
| 3 | 27-09-2013 | Success |
| 3 | 14-10-2013 | Success |
| 3 | 15-10-2013 | Email |
| 3 | 18-10-2013 | Form |
| 3 | 19-10-2013 | Click |

If the first event for every group of `ID` is `Success` or followed by *Consecutive* `Success`(note
strictly start with and /or followed by consecutive `Success` )then I want to drop the ID from the dataframe(Drop all the rows for that `ID` from the `df`)

Also if the case where the group is this way :-

| ID | Date | Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 04-09-2013 | Success |
| 4 | 27-09-2013 | Success |
| 4 | 14-10-2013 | Email |
| 4 | 15-10-2013 | Email |
| 4 | 18-10-2013 | Success |
| 4 | 18-10-2013 | Success |
| 4 | 18-10-2013 | Click |

Expected output to be (i.e a.)remove rows if the first event/consecutive events are `Success` and also b.)drop the events(rows) after the last/latest success within each group(taken one example of Event click but if there are more events those are to be dropped as well):

| ID | Date | Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 14-10-2013 | Email |
| 4 | 15-10-2013 | Email |
| 4 | 18-10-2013 | Success |
| 4 | 18-10-2013 | Success |

b.) is valid for every group irrespective of how the Event starts( for example ) :-

| ID | Date | Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 14-10-2013 | Email |
| 5 | 15-10-2013 | Click |
| 5 | 18-10-2013 | Success |
| 5 | 18-10-2013 | Email |

Expected :-

| ID | Date | Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 14-10-2013 | Email |
| 5 | 15-10-2013 | Click |
| 5 | 18-10-2013 | Success |

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What do you mean by “consecutive success”? The 2nd row of the group is “Success”?

Comment: Please, clarify what you mean by the second part, which starts after your words “Drop all the rows for that ID from the df”. It seems to contradict with the first part. Should we drop ALL or NOT ALL rows with this ID?

Comment: Have added an example for that as well.

Comment: Why don’t you “Drop all the rows for ” ID 4? It starts with “Success”, doesn’t it?

Comment: Because we have a Success event post the 2 event start success unlike the earlier one

Comment: I see that, but you are saying yourself: “If the first event for every group of ID is Success … then I want to drop the ID from the dataframe”. Does it matter at all what comes after it?

Comment: yes it does , That is why I have explained the cases. “If the first event for every group of ID is Success … then I want to drop the ID from the dataframe” is only whrn there are consecutive Success at start of group and there are no more Success events after other events within the group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#remove values after last Success per groups + not remove only non Success groups
df = df.iloc[::-1]
m = df['Event'].eq('Success')
df  = df[~m.groupby(df['ID']).transform('all') | m.groupby(df['ID']).cummax()].iloc[::-1]

#remove first conscutive Success per groups
m1 = df['Event'].ne(df.groupby(df['ID'])['Event'].shift()).groupby(df['ID']).cumsum().ne(1)
#alternative solution
#m1 = df['Event'].mask(df['Event'].eq('Success')).groupby(df['ID']).ffill().notna()
m2 = df['Event'].ne('Success')

df = df[m1 | m2]
print (df)
    ID        Date    Event
8    4  14-10-2013    Email
9    4  15-10-2013    Email
10   4  18-10-2013  Success
11   4  18-10-2013  Success
13   5  14-10-2013    Email
14   5  15-10-2013    Click
15   5  18-10-2013  Success
```